# How can I find the time difference in hour between the separated columns of date and time that are string data types?

Tags: sql, sqlite

| Date | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 10/26/2002 | 9:23 |
| 11/3/2005 | 11:33 |

I have separated column of date and time in this form and the data type for both columns are text. I would like to find the time difference between 2 and 1 in hour; however, I tried to convert the data type to datetime by using CAST(Date as Datetime) it didn't work. Is it possible to concatenate the two columns first and then find the difference between the timestamp?

Comment: You have a few challenges here. SQL commands work on each record, but you wish to operate on separate records to do a calculation ?   You also have date parts that are not consistent in length, this makes processing in SQL difficult.  What you wish to do is fairly simple if you use a programming language of your choice to do it (pretty much every language connects to SQLite these days).

Comment: Another challenge: dates are not in [valid sqlite data format](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values).